# Pseudo-JSON breakdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex

I'm having code like this (can't change its nature) and what I want to do is to break it down to access data in a JSON-esque way

```
product:{
    name:[
      {
        language:"en_US",
        value:"Apocalypse Now"
      }
    ],
    description:[
      {
        language_tag:"en_US",
        value:"Good!"
      }
    ]
}
```

So I would like to access it like product.name.value.

I tried different Regexp solutions as it's not a real JSON (missing quotation marks amongst other things) but I cannot seem to get it sturdy enough to isolate information in a proper way.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not the way to go. You can't parse a programming language with regexes. Your realistic options are

- `eval` (fine if input is trusted and performance is not a concern)
- a full-blown Javascript parser: [`esprima`](https://esprima.org/)
- a javascript-to-json parser (mine): [`litr`](https://github.com/gebrkn/litr)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realized though that by replacing "product:" with nothing and using it as a variable it turns out to be a valid Javascript object, hence I can access it. However I will deep dive in the resources you provided me with

Comment: @AndreRetroPie: ah, ok. I interpreted your question as if you had a string with that content. If this is actual javascript, the answer doesn't apply.

Comment: Ok other question though: if that is a string, how to convert it in an actual object? JSON Parse won't work on this one

Comment: If that is a string, then one of the options I've listed should work.